# Save MKV file from VLC with subtitle delay?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I currently have a set of MKV files with subtitles all offset with a delay of one second. I figured out that you can use File -> Convert/Save in VLC to save the video with [command line](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) options.

The particular option I am using is subsdelay-mode and subsdelay-factor using the following steps:

1. Open VLC
2. Media -> Convert/Save
3. File Selection -> Add...
4. Select video file
5. Check "Show more options"
6. Write in "Edit Options" -> ":file-caching=300:subsdelay-mode=0:subsdelay-factor=-1.0"
7. Click "Convert/Save"
8. Settings -> Check "Dump raw input" (keeps from changing the output(.mkv) format)

That should be all of the appropriate steps for loading up my video, offsetting the subtitles with a hastening(negative delay) of 1 second. However, this doesn't work. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is that `Dump raw input` means to use the input (including the subtitles) without any change, so the `subsdelay--factor` doesn't do anything.

VLC isn't the right program for this job. You should use a demuxer/muxer to change the subtitle-stream.

demux the mkv-file -> you get the subtitle-stream
edit the stream with your custom delay
remux the mkv-file with the new subtitle-stream

[mkvtoolnix](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) should be able to do this